# xcode potential leak of an object stored into "array"

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsarray

```
NSArray * array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Top"] mutableCopy];
NSString * cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and I get this error:

`potential leak of an object stored into "array"`

How can I fix this without migrating to **ARC**. Please help, and thanks a million in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to make a `mutableCopy` of the array? Also, are you `releasing` the array when you are done with it?

Comment: yes I did use [array release] but was getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

Because you're creating a new object (methods with `copy` give object with reference count 1) you need to release it.

The error refers to the array stored in the `array` variable. If you're not using it outside this function or you're later assigning it to a property that would retain it, then autorelease it:

```
 NSArray *array = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Top"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: autorelease dit id, Thanks,